What is going wrong when I try to run a Phylogenetic Generalized Least Squares analysis in R?
I've tried to run PGLS in R two different ways recently and I keep running into errors that I can't find information about in the specific packages. I'm using RStudio, not the command line version in case that makes a difference.
The first way I tried, I've run before but now when I try to do it, I get an error:

"R session aborted and R encountered a fatal error.

library(ape)
library(nlme)
thoracic <- X2024_Locomotion_for_R$Thoracic
locomotion <- X2024_Locomotion_for_R$`Locomotor Type`
pglsModel <- gls(thoracic ~ locomotion, correlation = corBrownian(phy = tree27),
                 data = X2024_Locomotion_for_R, method = "ML")

I've determined the error occurs after the third line. The two columns that start with X2024 are imported into R from Excel. Thoracic is a quantitative list, locomotion is a qualitative list, and they're long lists, which may be why I'm getting an error.
I've heard that uninstalling and reinstalling R can help with the above error, but I've done that twice and the error persists.
I tried another package after reading a PGLS tutorial online (which I can link if asked). I've been getting stuck at the second step though.
library(caper)
locomotion_PGLS <- comparative.data(tree27, X2024_Locomotion_for_R, X2024_Locomotion_for_R$`Combined Binomial Name`, vcv=FALSE, vcv.dim=2, na.omit=TRUE, force.root=FALSE, warn.dropped=FALSE, scope=NULL)

I get this error:

"Error in if (is.na(namesInd)) { : the condition has length > 1".

I looked up the error here and on the caper package's webpage. I can't find any information about this error. The information I have been able to find refers to functions and packages doesn't seem to match up with what I'm doing.

Hi user25179171, welcome to SO. It is important to provide a minimal, reproducible example when asking a question. This link has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. If your data are too large to share, it might suffice to provide a subset. You can also create a 'toy' dataset if your data are confidential. Good luck!
